# Accessing data from file

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I'm aware this has been discussed a lot on SO (and elsewhere). I'm resorting to asking here as I'm still stuck. Maybe I'm doing something really brainless/silly or maybe it's a genuine gotcha...

I have a directory of files, each with the extension '.pts' - opening one reveals:

> version: 1
>
> n_points:  68
>
> {
>
> 498.801220 504.771171
>
> 516.076459 571.681686
>
> 518.038170 628.516761
>   ...

Pasting here gets the formatting wrong a little, so be advised that there is no empty line between each line of data. There are also 68 of these float pairs, however I omit them here.

Eventually I want a vector of the pairs as rounded shorts - e.g. 499, 505, 516, 572, 518, 629 ...

But at the moment I can't access the floats as is, let alone any information.

The code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "dirent.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

bool has_suffix(const string& s, const string& suffix)
{
    return (s.size() >= suffix.size()) && equal(suffix.rbegin(), suffix.rend(), s.rbegin());    
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string path = "C:\\testset";
    DIR *dir = opendir(path.c_str());
    if(!dir)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    dirent *entry;

    string fileName;

    float number;
    string dummy;

    while(entry = readdir(dir))
    {
        if(has_suffix(entry->d_name, ".pts"))
        {
            fileName = entry->d_name;
            fileName = path + "\\" + fileName;   // <<added at suggestion of Martin James

            //Working up to here as I see all the .pts files listed when I print them:
            cout << fileName << endl;

            ifstream file(fileName, std::ios_base::in);

            //however from here:
            while (file >> number)
            {
                //...nothing will print
                printf("%f ", number);
            }

            file.close();
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

Finding all the .pts files is working (thanks other thread on SO :) - and they do appear to be simple .text files as they open in text editors. There is a 'LF' at the end of each line.

Problem is that running the code will only result in the file names being listed. It seems that "while (file >> number)" isn't returning anything to run the print statement. Thing is, other threads on the topic indicate (at least to me) that it is as simple as this.

I feel it's likely that the answer will involve things I've looked at in the last few hours -  dummy string variables to soak up all the stuff at the top of the file I don't need? getline? 'tokens'? I would show you all my attempts at nutting it out but I don't want to bog down the question:

**Given a txt file formatted like above how would you access the values from line 4 onwards?**

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I suspect 'ifstream file(fileName, std::ios_base::in);'. 'fileName' is not a complete path amd the initialization constructor has failed.  For some reason, this does not raise an exception?

Comment: True! I've added:  "fileName = path + "\\" + fileName;" and can see the full path printed out now... However, still not accessing any values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that, you are not reading in the header information. The `>>` operation fails, because you are trying to read in the string "version: 1" as a float.

To fix this, you should either skip the header with few calls to `std::getline` or parse it to get information about the contents.

**Edit:** To skip the lines you can just do:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) //Skip header
     std::getline(file,dummy);
```

Comment: arrrgh... I knew this! Even tried it, I guess something wrong in the syntax or some silly error...  Much obliged - have a great break over the years end if you're having one!   EDIT: I guess the other mistake in the code pointed out by Martin James would have been an obvious deal breaker.